# Can celery assign task to specify worker

Tags: python, celery

Celery will send task to idle workers.

I have a task will run every 5 seconds, and I want this task to only be sent to one specify worker.

Other tasks can share the left over workers

Can celery do this??

And I want to know what this parameter is: `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES`
Does it means that the task will not be sent to a worker in the queue?
Or does it stop the task if it runs too long?

Answer (score 10):

Sure, you can. Best way to do it, separate celery workers using different queues. You just need to make sure that task you need goes to separate queue, and your worker listening particular queue.
Long story for this: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html

Comment: But there is a variant when I can have a multiple workers(on each instance for example) of one queue.

Comment: @KravAn if so, what is wrong?  Multiple workers may listen same queue

Comment: For example you have one queue and lot of workers which execute tasks from this queue and have another queue(for task revoking), and you want revoke specific task. So how can you send a message to a specific worker(from 'revoke' queue) to stop task executing by specific worker from first queue. I have this issue and using broadcasting, but I don't know how to send a message to a specific worker.

Comment: Excuse me, I can't understand what you're trying to do - Since you're sending to queue you cannot control worker who picks that tasks. Want to cancel? Send separate message as cancelling - see celery docs they support that,

Answer (score -1):

Just to answer your second question `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES` is the time in seconds that the result of the task is persisted. So after a task is over, its result is saved into your result backend. The result is kept there for the amount of time specified by that parameter. That is used when a task result might be accessed by different callers.

This has probably nothing to do with your problem. As for the first solution, as already stated you have to use multiple queues. However be aware that you cannot assign the task to a specific Worker Process, just to a specific Worker which will then assign it to a specific Worker Process.