# (celery) :Run task in a specific worker?

Tags: celery, worker, celery-task

I have many workers from different server in celery,(the below picture shows)
[image]

and many tasks:

```
@task(name="task1")
def task1():
   .......

@task(name="task2")
def task2():
   ......
```

I want to run "task1" only on the "celery@40.218testlab_website" worker. How should I config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can celery assign task to specify worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468024/can-celery-assign-task-to-specify-worker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give you workers different names, assign each worker to read from a specific queue when running, aka:

```
celery -A tasks -n worker1 -q queue1 --loglevel=info
celery -A tasks -n worker2 -q queue2 --loglevel=info
...
```

and than add [router](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html), for example:

```
def route_task(name, args, kwargs, options, task=None, **kw):
        if name == 'task1':
            return 'queue1'
        elif name == 'task2':
            return 'queue2'
        return None
```

Note, the implementation depends on the celery version you run (i'm using 3.1) - it changed a little in 4.
There are even simpler router in the link I've added (in configuration) - check this out.

Good luck

Comment: Great, Thank you very much @itayB